# 'TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable' when trying to compare a list of dates with a single date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a nested list like this:

```
nl = [['a', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)], 
      ['b', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)],
      ['c', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 0, 0)], 
      ['d', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 0, 0)]
```

And a single date like this:

```
date_today = datetime.date(2020, 2, 6)
```

I want to remove all sublists which contain an older date than date_today.

Like this:

```
date_l = []
for line in nl:
    if line[1] > date_today:
        date_l.append[line]
```

However I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please share the full error message. Have you checked if the contents of `line` are what you expect? I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Why is it a `datetime.datetime` and/or why would you want to iterate it?

Comment: I can’t reproduce this. When I run it, I get a different error: `if line[1] > date_today: TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`

Comment: This can't be your actual code; the final `]` is missing. Anyway, is something messing with the contents of `nl` in the interim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
        nl = [['a', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)],
              ['b', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)],
              ['c', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 0, 0)],
              ['d', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 0, 0)]]

        date_today = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6,0,0)
        date_l = []
        for line in nl:

            if line[1] > date_today:
                date_l.append(line)
        print(date_l)
```

Result : [['a', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)], ['b', datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0)]]